Long Run Query to Perform Metric from Previous and Next Date in Big Query
I have a table which contain date and a metric. I want to be able to add the metric with value of the next month and also metric with the value of last year from the next month date. I have got no problem with my query, however, it took long time to run. Even after 1 hour, it still haven't finish running.
Here's my example of my table.
And here's my query in Big Query
WITH first_table AS (
  SELECT current_date, next1month_date, DATE(DATETIME_SUB(next1month_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AS previous_date, metric
  FROM (SELECT current_date, DATE(DATETIME_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS next1month_date, metric
    FROM `table.name`)
),

second_table AS (
  SELECT current_date, future_metric
  FROM (SELECT current_date, metric AS future_metric
    FROM `table.name`)
),

third_table AS (
  SELECT a.current_date, a.next1month_date, a.previous_date, a.metric, b.future_metric
  FROM first_table AS a FULL JOIN second_table AS b 
  ON a.next1month_date = b.new_date
),

forth_table AS (
  SELECT current_date, previous_metric
  FROM (SELECT current_date, actual AS previous_metric
    FROM `table.name`)
)

SELECT c.current_date, c.next1month_date, c.previous_date, c.metric, c.future_metric, d.previous_metric
FROM third_table AS c FULL JOIN forth_table AS d
ON c.next1month_date = d.metric_date

And the result should be something like this:



current_date
metric
next1month_date
future_metric
previous_date
previous_metric




30 Jun 2024
235345
31 Jul 2024
null
31 Jul 2023
78


31 Aug 2022
46457
30 Sep 2022
4564
30 Sep 2021
null


31 Jan 2024
6867
29 Feb 2024
46356
28 Feb 2023
345



The problem here is why it take quite long for the query to be execute? Is there any problem with my query? Is there's any, what's the wrong in my query and how should I fix it?

The query makes use of two FULL JOIN, which require some time. My guess is that the table has several entries per date. Thus please summarize that table by date.
WITH table_one as (
SELECT DATE(current_date) AS current_date, SUM(metric) AS metric
FROM `table.name`
GROUP by 1
)


SELECT A.*,
B.metric AS previous_metric,
C.metric AS future_metric,
B.current_date AS previous_date,
C.current_date AS future_date,
FROM table_one A
FULL JOIN table_one B ON A.current_date=DATETIME_ADD(B.current_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
FULL JOIN table_one C ON A.current_date=DATETIME_SUB(C.current_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)


